# Power BI Dataset DataSource Credentials

Tags: powerbi, report

I have a dataset, which uses a locale data gateway. 
When i try to refresh the dataset i get following message:
[image]

Then i go to the dataset settings, where i can't click on "Data source credentials".. Under "Gateway conncetion" it displays this (i use the gateway in the border):
[image]

Then i check Gateways under "manage Gateways" where everything is ok.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anyone explain me what i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check Privacy Level ..try with Organisational or None?

[image]